# From XML to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phalcon

I have loaded my XML file with PHP simpleXML but I have next situation ... My XML file looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <status>1</status>
    <market>
      <shop>
          <url>https://some.api.link.with.products.of.shop.com/file_with_products.xml</url>
          <shopId>1</shopId>
          <name>First shop</name>
      </shop>
      <shop>
          <url>https://some.api.link.with.products.of.shop.com/file_with_products.xml</url>
          <shopId>2</shopId>
          <name>Second shop</name>
      </shop>
    </market>
</xml>
```

I'm accessing this XML data like a objects :

```
foreach($xml->market->shop as $shop)
    {
        echo $shop->url;
        echo $shop->storeId;
        echo $shop->name;
    }
```

Is there a way to access data from this url links (which is also an XML file with products list of that shop) ? So every shop have url link with XML file of his products. I have to get all data and store in MySQL databse (all data means shops data from main XML file and data from url links which are product list of that shop). Im also using phalcon framework.

Comment: Well, just load the URLs itself via `file_get_contents()` and the parse that string with simplexml again.

Comment: I have a 500+ shops in this main XML file, this is just example that i wrote up .. So i have to load all shops data from this main XML and load XML files (url link) of every shop to get their products ...

Comment: Yes, this is basically what you have to do then. You can of course try to optmize things by checking for HTTP cache headers on the given URLs so you can skip things to process that you already have processed earlier (given that your "upstream" XML resource delivers proper cache headers), but that's about it.

Comment: If you wouldn't run on single-threaded PHP, you could also try and parallize / map-reduce the processing of the individual shop data, but yeah, PHP is a bitch in this regard. **Edit** Don't mind this - there is a PECL module now apparently that offers threading via pthreads: https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads.

Comment: Ok, but here is a little problem. My script now works well when Im using XML file from my local machine, but when I try to read it directly from URL, I get those errors..

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /var/www/html/myproject.local/test1.php on line 4 <br/>

Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://link_from_my_xml_file.xml): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /var/www/html/myproject.local/test1.php on line 4 <br/>

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://link_from_my_xml_file.xml" in /var/www/html/myproject.local/test1.php on line 4 <br/>

Comment: Well, the error already tells you everything: `getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname` - what is the hostname of the URL you're trying to load? Can it be resolved via `nslookup` / is it reachable at all?

Comment: The problem was caused by Vagrant. Im using a developmnet statck (Ubuntu VBox), and that caused some issue with "hosts". Everything works fine, thx for help.